# Alert in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to use `alert` in my reactjs front-end. I just used the very basic alert mechanism like `alert("error msg")`. However, is there any better/optimized way in reactjs for alert prompt like this? The alert is not in a rendering function so I did not use `Alert` from `react-bootstrap`.

Comment: [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) might suit your needs.

Comment: Instead of using different libraries you can one library for all the stuff. You can use react ant library for all these stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`react-animated-modal`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animated-modal) to show alerts in reactjs. It has 40 animations provided by `Animate.css`